# What is the class of int array?

Tags: java, class, object

Problem1:
I have a doubt that if we can only create objects of class then  how are we able to create objects of primitive data types such as int,char etc.

Problem2:
Now suppose Ankit is a class and if I write

```
Ankit a=new Ankit();
System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
```

it will give me class name of a. Also if I write

```
System.out.println(Ankit.class);
```

Then too it will give class name.But If I write

```
int ar[]=new int[10];
System.out.println(ar.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(int.class);
```

then I get output as:

[I   and   int

Why so? Here also I should get same output as class name of int ar then why different outputs and what is [I?

Comment: Hint: Do not declare array-typed variables as `int ar[]` (although the Java syntax allows that), but declare them as `int[] ar` instead. Then you see that you better write `System.out.println(int[].class)` as this is the correct array type.

Comment: Regarding the "problem 1": You cannot declare objects of _primitive_ types. It is the nature of primitive types that they are not object-oriented. You can only create objects of _reference_ types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are little different with `toString` implementation.

Here is the docs of what you seeing [getName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) docs

> Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object, as a String.
>   If this class object represents a reference type that is not an array type then the binary name of the class is returned, as specified by The Java™ Language Specification.
>
> If this class object represents a primitive type or void, then the name returned is a String equal to the Java language keyword corresponding to the primitive type or void.
>
> **If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more '[' characters representing the depth of the array nesting.** The encoding of element type names is as follows:

```
Element Type        Encoding
boolean     Z
byte        B
char        C
class or interface      Lclassname;
double      D
float       F
**int       I**
long        J
short       S
```

Comment: And primitives have non-FQN identifiers, like `Z` for boolean and `I` for int

Comment: @Rogue exactly. just mentioned that as well.

Comment: Java doc says: "If this class object represents a primitive type or void, then the name returned is a String equal to the Java language keyword corresponding to the primitive type or void."   but if I write int i=10; System.out.println(i.getClass().getName()); then it gives compile time error why so?

Comment: @Ankit because you can't invoke methods on primitive types.

Comment: primitives don't have invocable methods. Try `Integer` or `int[]` to see those in effect

Answer (score 5):

Your second snippet does not do the same as your first snippet. Instead, you're printing

1. The class name of an int array
2. The class name of a primitive int

You should change the last line of your snippet to:

```
System.out.println(int[].class);
```

to make it print the same thing as the line above.

About the second part of your question: that's just how java represents class name for arrays.

- A one-dimensional array of `int` is `[I`
- A two-dimensional array of `int` is `[[I`
- A one-dimensional array of your class `Ankit` is `[LAnkit;` (which you can observe with `System.out.println(Ankit[].class);`)